# Does someone have a PHP function to properly capitalize people names?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a function to properly capitalize names like McDonald, FitzGerald, MacArthur, O'Lunney's, Theo de Raadt, etc.

Does anyone know of one that works resonably well? I'm guessing any function is not going to support every possibility.

Of course ucwords alone doesn't work for this because it just capitalize the first letter of every word.

**Edit:** I know there are going to be problems and all the possibility are not going to be supported. But the issue right now is I have a database of around 50 000 names that are mostly entered in all caps and it would be a pain in the ass to have to edit each one without causing spelling errors. Having a script that causes a problem with 20% would be a whole lot faster and result in a lot fewer errors.

Comment: You may not have much luck with this question as some names aren't always capitalized in the way you think they should be. For example, I've seen Fitzgerald much more often than FitzGerald. And who's to say it shouldn't be a hyphenated name, like Fitz-Gerald?

Comment: What therefromhere said below; and also, many Dutch names (for example) don't have all the first characters capitalized, like "Theo de Raadt".

Comment: TIL Fitzgerald can be spelled [with different capitalisation or hyphenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzGerald_(surname)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this [ucwords function note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php#60064)

Comment: I did see this one while looking around and it looks quite good. There are also a few others that look good. Basically wondering if someone has one they have used and have found works well.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably aware of this, but one huge problem you'll face is that there's more than one "correct" capitalisation of some names - in your example I'd disagree with FitzGerald, for example.

Comment: This is true, but again, it's just a general fix. Right now I have database where >50% of people are entered with all caps.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I use

```
$output = trim(implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_',' ',$input)))))));
```

handy if you are storing `_` instead of spaces in your DB, or using them in urls, handles hyphenated names well too.

Also saw this somewhere that seems to do a good job in most cases

```
   /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    public function titleCase($string)
    {

        $word_splitters = array(' ', '-', "O'", "L'", "D'", 'St.', 'Mc', 'Mac');
        $lowercase_exceptions = array('the', 'van', 'den', 'von', 'und', 'der', 'de', 'di', 'da', 'of', 'and', "l'", "d'");
        $uppercase_exceptions = array('III', 'IV', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX');

        $string = strtolower($string);
        foreach ($word_splitters as $delimiter) {
            $words = explode($delimiter, $string);
            $newwords = array();
            foreach ($words as $word) {
                if (in_array(strtoupper($word), $uppercase_exceptions))
                    $word = strtoupper($word);
                else
                    if (!in_array($word, $lowercase_exceptions))
                        $word = ucfirst($word);

                $newwords[] = $word;
            }

            if (in_array(strtolower($delimiter), $lowercase_exceptions))
                $delimiter = strtolower($delimiter);

            $string = join($delimiter, $newwords);
        }
        return $string;
    }
```

names like Jurgen Macho (a footballer) is returned as Jurgen MacHo though, as pointed out in other answers and comments, names are hard.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
/**
  * Normalize the given (partial) name of a person.
  *
  * - re-capitalize, take last name inserts into account
  * - remove excess white spaces
  *
  * Snippet from: https://timvisee.com/blog/snippet-correctly-capitalize-names-in-php
  *
  * @param string $name The input name.
  * @return string The normalized name.
  */
function name_case($name) {
    // A list of properly cased parts
    $CASED = [
      "O'", "l'", "d'", 'St.', 'Mc', 'the', 'van', 'het', 'in', "'t", 'ten',
      'den', 'von', 'und', 'der', 'de', 'da', 'of', 'and', 'the', 'III', 'IV',
      'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX',
    ];

    // Trim whitespace sequences to one space, append space to properly chunk
    $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $name) . ' ';

    // Break name up into parts split by name separators
    $parts = preg_split('/( |-|O\'|l\'|d\'|St\\.|Mc)/i', $name, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    // Chunk parts, use $CASED or uppercase first, remove unfinished chunks
    $parts = array_chunk($parts, 2);
    $parts = array_filter($parts, function($part) {
            return sizeof($part) == 2;
        });
    $parts = array_map(function($part) use($CASED) {
            // Extract to name and separator part
            list($name, $separator) = $name;

            // Use specified case for separator if set
            $cased = current(array_filter($CASED, function($i) use($separator) {
                return strcasecmp($i, $separator) == 0;
            }));
            $separator = $cased ? $cased : $separator;

            // Choose specified part case, or uppercase first as default
            $cased = current(array_filter($CASED, function($i) use($name) {
                return strcasecmp($i, $name) == 0;
            }));
            return [$cased ? $cased : ucfirst(strtolower($name)), $separator];
        }, $parts);
    $parts = array_map(function($part) {
            return implode($part);
        }, $parts);
    $name = implode($parts);

    // Trim and return normalized name
    return trim($name);
}
```

It uses a list of parts for which is assumed the casing is correct. It will never be perfect, but it might improve things for your implementation.